# How can I count the number of unique hits on a graphene query

Tags: graphene-python

I searched a bit couldn't find a decent solution.
I would like to count the number of unique hits on a graphene query.
The frontend is react + apollo if that matters.
Any recommendation?

Let me clarify the question;
I would like to count the number of unique hits (ip&user agent&whatever) to the graphene query/endpoint  (graphql; not db).

Comment: Will have to write a Middleware which extracts the operation name and updates DB/store accordingly. Writing middleware is incredibly easy, I am yet to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you, you'd like to count unique hits to DB. I think the best solution for you, should be used [Django Debug Middleware](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/debug/). If you correctly add Debug Middleware you will need to add to your query:

```
_debug {
    sql {
      rawSql
    }
  }
```

After that you in `_debug` section you will have clear SQL query to DB.

Comment: Clarified the question sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `get_node` function given by `DjangoObjectType`.
I assume that you already use `DjangoObjectType` to define your node and `YourCustomModel` have a field named `view_count`.

Here's how you can do this:

```
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
    
class YourCustomNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = YourCustomModel
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = {
            ...
        }
    
    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, id):
        queryset = cls.get_queryset(cls._meta.model.objects, info)
        try:
            obj = YourCustomModel.objects.get(id=id)
            obj.view_count += 1
            obj.save(update_fields=['view_count', ])
            return queryset.get(pk=id)
        except cls._meta.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: You can even add one more try...except inside the first one to be sure that `YourCustomModel.objects.get(id=id)` exist.